# Iterate over an array of objects and mint an NFT on NEAR protocol

Tags: rust, nft, nearprotocol

I have this method:

```
#[payable]
pub fn nft_mint(&mut self, nft_list: Vec<Nft>) -> Vec<Token> {
    let mut t_result: Vec<Token> = Vec::new();
    for nft in nft_list {
        let s = self.tokens.mint(nft.token_id, nft.receiver_id, Some(nft.token_metadata));
        t_result.push(s);
    }
    return t_result;
}
```

and from frontend:

```
let token_list = [{
    token_id: nanoid(),
    receiver_id: window.accountId,
    token_metadata: { id: i, title: "test", myNumber: 123, price: 10, url: "http://..."}
  }];

    window.contract
      .nft_mint({ nft_list: token_list })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log("Success", res);
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log("Error", err);
      });
```

after deploying and initializing the contract, when I try to call the method, even that I have enough NEAR (on testnet 190NEAR) I get this error:

> ```
> {
>   "type": "action",
>   "error": {
>     "type": "functionCallError",
>     "error": {
>       "type": "executionError",
>       "error": "Smart contract panicked: panicked at 'Must attach 6290000000000000000000 
>
> yoctoNEAR to cover storage',
>  /home/HideThePainHarold/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecass99db9ec823/near-contract-standards-3.2.0/src/non_fungible_token/utils.rs:33:5"
>
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

and how would I make the sender pay for the actual minting (not just gas fees)?

Answer (score 2):

Storing information on-chain costs $NEAR. The smart contract chargers users who mint NFTs for the $NEAR that it costs. At the time of writing this, it costs 1 $NEAR for every 100kb of data stored.

If the smart contract didn't charge the user and minting was open to the public (not allowlisted), the contract could be subject to a [storage attack](https://docs.near.org/develop/contracts/security/storage).

All you need to do to fix your problem is attach $NEAR to the call.

To gain a better understanding as to what's happening behind the scenes, there's a great section of the NFT zero to hero tutorial that talks about [minting NFTs](https://docs.near.org/tutorials/nfts/minting).

Comment: thx. But isn't it per system already defined that you have to pay gas (#[payable]) for the transaction? so how can that be a storage attack when it already cost gas? (I know the principle of gas fees) - but why I am not able to make the transaction with that method which is already there? (not additional $NEAR payment.. just the minting with gas fees)

Comment: @Suisse Gas is different than attached deposits. Check out this article here:
https://docs.near.org/concepts/web3/near#gas-and-storage